# Right alignment of subchap and item list different

Tags: alignment, cv

I'm creating my CV in **Overleaf** (copied a template) and have a long list of items to include, with dates aligned to the right.

For some things like my qualifications I have listed them using the `\subchap` command to give them prominence. 
Then for some other areas I have a `\suchap` heading (without a date) but lesser items listed using the `\item` and `\hfill` commands.

Unfortunately the dates from the `\subchap` and `\hfill` commands don't align. 
[image]

Can you please help?

Here is a MWE (I hope):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nejm]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{      
    urlcolor=black,
}
\addbibresource{Mendeley_My_publications.bib}
\input{config/minimal-resume-config}

\begin{document}

% ------------------
% Personal (includes three rows: Name, Address, Contact)
% ------------------

\personal{
  % Name
   DR \, BOY\, NAME
  }{

  BSci, PhD
  }{

  M: {1234567}\hspace{\sizethree}E: boy@email.com
}


% ------------------
% Chapter: Qualifications
% ------------------

\chap{QUALIFICATIONS}{

  \subchap{Fellow of The College}{2020}{
  }

  \subchap{PhD `Trials and tribulations', University of Somewhere}{2015}{
  }

% ------------------
% Chapter: Teaching experience
% ------------------

\chap{TEACHING \& SUPERVISION}{

  \subchap{Professional Teaching}{}{
    \begin{newitemize}
    \item Online College Learning Series contributor \hfill{2019-current}

    \item Big presentation-- Update,  Some location \hfill{ 2019}

    \item Another case contributor \hfill{2018}
   \end{newitemize}
  }

  \subchap{Postgraduate Teaching}{}{
    \begin{newitemize}
     \item  Lecturer (Level B-6), School of Learning, The University of Here\hfill{2019-current}



     \item Tutor for the Postgraduate Program, The University of Here\hfill{2010}
    \end{newitemize}
  }


\centering
End of document
\\
\resizebox{12mm}{\height}{$\large \sim$}\hspace{ -7.3mm }$\scriptstyle \not\,\not$ \hspace{5mm}


\end{document}
```

Thanks to Mensch for your comment. I'm not sure how to best provide the information you have requested but tried to include it below (please let me know if I haven't done this properly).

`minimal-resume-config` contains the following code

```
\usepackage{config/minimal-resume}

% custom command and packages

\input{config/custom-command}
```

`minimal-resume.sty` contains the following:

```
% margin
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}

% minimal custom packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[fontsize=10.75pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

% font families
\newfontfamily{\montserratfont}[Path=fonts/,BoldFont=Montserrat-Bold]{Montserrat-Regular}
\newfontfamily{\crimsonfont}[Path=fonts/,ItalicFont=CrimsonText-Italic]{CrimsonText-Roman}

% main font for the document
\setmainfont[Path=fonts/, ItalicFont=CrimsonText-Italic]{CrimsonText-Roman}

% font sizes
\newcommand{\sizeone}{1.618em}
\newcommand{\sizetwo}{1.318em}
\newcommand{\sizethree}{1em}
\newcommand{\sizefour}{0.618em}
\newcommand{\sizefive}{0.382em}
\newcommand{\sizesix}{0.236em}

% line spaces
\newcommand{\linespaceone}{1}

\newenvironment{newitemize}
  {\itemize[nolistsep,topsep=\sizefive,itemsep=\sizefive,labelsep=\sizefour,leftmargin=*]}
  {\enditemize}

\newcommand{\personal}[3]{
  \begin{center}
    % name
    {
      \fontsize{\sizeone}{\sizeone}\fontspec[Path = fonts/,LetterSpace=15]{Montserrat-Regular}#1
    }\\
    % address
    \vspace{\sizethree}
    {
      \fontsize{\sizethree}{\sizethree}\fontspec[Path = fonts/,LetterSpace= 10]{Montserrat-Light}#2
    }\\
    % contact
    \vspace{\sizefive}
    {
      \fontsize{\sizethree}{\sizethree}\fontspec[Path = fonts/]{Montserrat-Light}#3
    }
  \end{center}
}

\newcommand{\chap}[2]{
  \vspace{\sizethree}
  \raggedright
  {\hrule height 0.5pt}
  \vspace{\sizefive}
  \begin{addmargin}[\sizefive]{\sizefive}{
  {
  \fontsize{\sizefour}{\sizefour}\fontspec[Path = fonts/,LetterSpace=10]{Montserrat-Bold}
  \textbf{#1}
  }
  \vspace{\sizefour}
  {#2}
  }
  \end{addmargin}
}

\newcommand{\subchap}[3]{
  \vspace{\sizefive}
  {\fontsize{\sizetwo}{\sizetwo}\fontspec[Path = fonts/]{CrimsonText-Roman} #1} \hfill {\fontsize{\sizetwo}{\sizetwo}\fontspec[Path = fonts/]{CrimsonText-Roman} #2}
  {#3}
  \vspace{\sizefive}
}
```

Again thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, in your file `minimal-resume.sty` are fonts used which are not standard fonts, your code is still uncompilable (did you test it is compilable?) I think it would be best you can add an link to that template one can check without be forced to register on overleaf ... And perhaps you can add an screenshot of your result and marking there your issue?

Comment: Thank you Mensch- sorry I haven't provided the necessary info so far (i'm not sure how to check if it is compilable)
The template can be accessed from here: 
https://github.com/RatulSaha/Minimal-Resume

I have posted a photo of the issue here:

Comment: Adding \null% after the \hfill{text} command works a bit, but not quite right

Comment: Changing the command to \hfil{text} doesn't work at all...

Comment: Changing the command to \hspace*{\fill} is no different to the original \hfill{text}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this template you are using is not the best. Have you considered to use another one?

Nevertheless, I see three main issues here:

1. You need to change the call for `\subcap` to

   ```
   \subchap{Fellow of The College}{Feb}{%
   2020}% <==============================================================
   ```

   Please see that I moved the year number into the third argument and added `Feb` into the second parameter ...
2. You need to redefine command `\subcap` to get rid of some spurious blanks like (see important code changings marked with `<======`):

   ```
   \renewcommand{\subchap}[3]{% <========================================== \re
     \vspace{\sizefive}
     {\fontsize{\sizetwo}{\sizetwo}\fontspec[Path = fonts/]{CrimsonText-Roman} #1} \hfill {\fontsize{\sizetwo}{\sizetwo}\fontspec[Path = fonts/]{CrimsonText-Roman} #2}
     {#3}% <=============================================================== %
     \vspace{\sizefive}% <================================================= %
   }
   ```

   Please see the first comment: I used `\renewcommand` to redefine an existing command, see second and third comment: added `%` to get rid of blanks ...
3. I commented line with `\resizebox` because that command is not defined in your code ...

Please see the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nejm]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Mendeley_My_publications.bib}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\usepackage{showframe} % <==============================================
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{      
    urlcolor=black,
}

%\input{config/minimal-resume-config}
\usepackage{config/minimal-resume}

\renewcommand{\subchap}[3]{% <==========================================
  \vspace{\sizefive}
  {\fontsize{\sizetwo}{\sizetwo}\fontspec[Path = fonts/]{CrimsonText-Roman} #1} \hfill {\fontsize{\sizetwo}{\sizetwo}\fontspec[Path = fonts/]{CrimsonText-Roman} #2}
  {#3}% <===============================================================
  \vspace{\sizefive}% <=================================================
}


\begin{document}

% ------------------
% Personal (includes three rows: Name, Address, Contact)
% ------------------

\personal{
  % Name
   DR \, BOY\, NAME
  }{

  BSci, PhD
  }{

  M: {1234567}\hspace{\sizethree}E: boy@email.com
}


% ------------------
% Chapter: Qualifications
% ------------------

\chap{QUALIFICATIONS}{%

  \subchap{Fellow of The College}{Feb}{%
  2020}% <==============================================================

  \subchap{PhD `Trials and tribulations', University of Somewhere}{2015}{%
  }%
} % <===================================================================

% ------------------
% Chapter: Teaching experience
% ------------------

\chap{TEACHING \& SUPERVISION}{

  \subchap{Professional Teaching}{}{
    \begin{newitemize}
    \item Online College Learning Series contributor \hfill 2019-current

    \item Big presentation-- Update,  Some location \hfill 2019

    \item Another case contributor \hfill 2018
   \end{newitemize}
  }

  \subchap{Postgraduate Teaching}{}{
    \begin{newitemize}
     \item  Lecturer (Level B-6), School of Learning, The University of Here\hfill{2019-current}



     \item Tutor for the Postgraduate Program, The University of Here\hfill{2010}
    \end{newitemize}
  }
} % <===================================================================


\centering
End of document
\\
%\resizebox{12mm}{\height}{$\large \sim$}\hspace{ -7.3mm }$\scriptstyle \not\,\not$ \hspace{5mm}


\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mensch for your solution, which worked well (although I don't understand why).
Could you please explain why the template is 'not the best'?

Comment: @richardbbq Well, have a look to macro `\subchap`: there are some `%` missing to avoid not wanted blanks (I added them in my redefinition of that macro). Then the used fonts are not defined at one place, they are spread all ofer the files of that template. Soif you want to change the font you have to check each line of that tex code of that template ... Not good ...